# std::runtime_error::what() causes access violation when using nested exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, windows-mobile, arm

I am not looking for a way to fix this issue, merely to understand the cause of it. A colleague showed me some code that was causing an Access Violation when compiled by Visual Studio 2008 to run under Windows Mobile 6 ARMV4I. This same code worked fine under x86 Windows and he claims it works under Linux compiled by GCC (I haven't verified that). I distilled the issue down to the code below:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    try
    {
        throw std::runtime_error( "a" );
    }
    catch( std::runtime_error& e1 )
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                throw std::runtime_error( "b" );
            }
            catch( std::runtime_error& e11 )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch( std::runtime_error& e12 )
        {
            e12.what(); // access violation
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Putting aside questions of whether or not this code is reasonable, can anybody explain what is causing the access violation when `std::runtime_error::what()` is called in the code above?

Thanks,
PaulH

**Edit:** The callstack:

```
test.exe!wmain(int argc = 1, wchar_t** argv = 0x00040080) Line: 169, Byte Offsets: 0xd8 C++
_CallSettingFrame   
test.exe!CallCatchBlock(EHExceptionRecord* pExcept = 0x1803eb0c, unsigned long int* pRN = 0x1803fc18, _CONTEXT* pContext = 0x1803f014, _s_FuncInfo* pFuncInfo = 0x00023960, void* handlerAddress = 0x00011494, int CatchDepth = 0, unsigned long int NLGCode = 256) Line: 878, Byte Offsets: 0x258  C++
test.exe!__InternalCxxFrameHandler(EHExceptionRecord* pExcept = 0x1803eb0c, unsigned long int* pRN = 0x1803f2f8, _CONTEXT* pContext = 0x1803f014, _DISPATCHER_CONTEXT* pDC = 0x1803e824, _s_FuncInfo* pFuncInfo = 0x00023960, int CatchDepth = 0) Line: 179, Byte Offsets: 0xfc C++
test.exe!__CxxFrameHandler3(EHExceptionRecord* pExcept = 0x1803eb0c, unsigned long int* pRN = 0x1803f2f8, _CONTEXT* pContext = 0x1803f014, _DISPATCHER_CONTEXT* pDC = 0x1803e824) Line: 242, Byte Offsets: 0x54 C++
0xf000fffc
```

The Output Window:

```
RaiseException: Thread=96ec78d0 Proc=80096c70 'test.exe'
AKY=00000801 PC=03f91e7c(coredll.dll+0x00043e7c) RA=88037538(NK.EXE+0x00007538) BVA=00000000 FSR=00000000
RaiseException: Thread=96ec78d0 Proc=80096c70 'test.exe'
AKY=00000801 PC=03f91e7c(coredll.dll+0x00043e7c) RA=88037538(NK.EXE+0x00007538) BVA=00000000 FSR=00000000
RaiseException: Thread=96ec78d0 Proc=80096c70 'test.exe'
AKY=00000801 PC=03f91e7c(coredll.dll+0x00043e7c) RA=88037538(NK.EXE+0x00007538) BVA=00000000 FSR=00000000
Data Abort: Thread=96ec78d0 Proc=80096c70 'test.exe'
AKY=00000801 PC=000114ac(test.exe+0x000014ac) RA=0002095c(test.exe+0x0001095c) BVA=5061654c FSR=00000405
First-chance exception at 0x000114ac in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x5061654c.
```

**Edit2:**
There is a [defect report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/357154/exception-handling-access-violation-on-nested-try-catchs#details) in Microsoft Connect regarding this issue.

Comment: I can verify that the code works just fine in GCC on both Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: Is the exception thrown across library boundaries? Make sure that the relevant (dynamic linkage) flags are in operation and that the libraries are being compiled withthe same compile time flags as the client code

Comment: @sehe - all that code is entirely within the `main()` function. no libraries other than the standard library are used.

Comment: @sehe - Yes, it does. But, I've removed it in the question to prevent confusion on the issue. The issue is the same even if all I do is call `e12.what();`

Comment: It's rare, but it could be a bug in the compiler's ARMV4I code generation - I bet it's not as well tested as the x86 or x64 code generators...

Comment: Make it compilable so people can easily test it. (ie add main and the required includes). Then ask people to post results from as many compiler variants as possible. Finally file a bug with the compiler manufacturer.

Comment: @Martin - added `main()` per your suggestion. Part of what I wanted to discover is if this was, in fact, a defect with the compiler or if I just did not understand some nuance of C++ exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a listing too long to be in a comment.

I looked up the assembly for Release build of the offending code. See below. I marked the AV on the correct instruction line 5 lines from the bottom.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
000116E8  mov         r12, sp 
000116EC  stmdb       sp!, {r11, r12, lr} 
000116F0  add         r11, sp, #0xC 
000116F4  sub         sp, sp, #0x98 
000116F8  ldr         r3, [pc, #0x10C] 
000116FC  ldr         r3, [r3] 
00011700  str         r3, [r11, #-0x10] 
    try
    {
        throw std::runtime_error( "a" );
00011704  mov         r2, #0 
00011708  mov         r1, #0 
0001170C  sub         r0, r11, #0x84 
00011710  bl          |std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Tidy ( 11118h )| 
00011714  ldr         r1, [pc, #0xEC] 
00011718  mov         r2, #1 
0001171C  sub         r0, r11, #0x84 
00011720  bl          |std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign ( 114d0h ) 
00011724  sub         r1, r11, #0x84 
00011728  sub         r0, r11, #0x68 
0001172C  bl          |std::runtime_error::runtime_error ( 115ach )| 
00011730  ldr         r1, [pc, #0xC4] 
00011734  sub         r0, r11, #0x68 
00011738  bl          000118F0 
    return 0;
0001173C  ldr         r0, [r11, #-0x10] 
00011740  bl          00011C70 
00011744  mov         r0, #0 
}
00011748  sub         sp, r11, #0xC 
0001174C  ldmia       sp, {r11, sp, pc} 
00011750  andeq       r3, r1, r8, ror r0 
00011754  andeq       r4, r1, r0, ror #3 
            }
            catch( std::runtime_error& e11 )
00011758  str         lr, [sp, #-4]! 
            {
                throw;
0001175C  mov         r1, #0 
00011760  mov         r0, #0 
00011764  bl          000118F0 
00011768  andeq       r3, r1, r8, ror r0 
0001176C  andeq       r4, r1, r0, ror #3 
            }
        }
        catch( std::runtime_error& e12 )
00011770  str         lr, [sp, #-4]! 
        {
            e12.what(); // access violation
00011774  ldr         r0, e12, #-0xA4 
00011778  ldr         r3, [r0]         // AV
0001177C  mov         lr, pc 
00011780  ldr         pc, [r3, #4] 
00011784  ldr         r0, [pc, #0x78] 
00011788  ldr         pc, [sp], #4
```